# Assigning and updating value for dynamically created input tags - jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Hello I have latest jquery and I have one table like below where on click on add button i am appending row of inputs, I want to calculate the total price of each particular (product) on key up(i.e. qty * price = total price), I am facing problem because I am having dynamically added inputs in a row, kindly suggest any solution for same.

Note: in want to achieve the solution using jquery/ javascript

[image: table where i am appending input row]

[image: jquery code for appending input rows]

```js
 $(function () {
       $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
           var div = $("<tr  />");
           div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
           $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
       });
       $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
           $(this).closest("tr").remove();
       });
   });
   function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
       return '<td><input name = "particular[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Particulars" required /></td>'+ '<td><input name = "hsn[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="HSN" required /></td>' + '<td><input name = "qty[]" type="number" class="form-control qty" placeholder="Quantity" required /></td>' + '<td><input name = "price[]" type="number" class="form-control price" placeholder="Price" required /></td>' + '<td><input name = "total[]" type="number" class="form-control total" placeholder="Total" required /></td>'  + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove materials items"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>'
   }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="particulars_table">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <td>Particular</td>
        <td>HSN</td>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td>Rate</td>
        <td>Action</td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
           <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success w-100" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more Materials"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>Add</button>
        </th>
     </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: please post your code as `text` not `images`.

Comment: $(function () {
       $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
           var div = $("<tr  />");
           div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
           $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
       });
       $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
           $(this).closest("tr").remove();
       });
   });

Comment: add above code in question asked not in comment .

Comment: sure i will add all code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keyup` and `change` method of jquery i.e: whenever the value of of quantity gets change get that value and we will be using `$(this)` to get required `tr` using this  we will get value of price and multiply `qty` and `price` together and assign value to `total` input .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
    var div = $("<tr  />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
  return '<td><input name = "particular[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Particulars" required /></td>' + '<td><input name = "hsn[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="HSN" required /></td>' + '<td><input name = "qty[]" type="number" class="form-control qty" placeholder="Quantity" required /></td>' + '<td><input name = "price[]" type="number" class="form-control price" placeholder="Price" required /></td>' + '<td><input name = "total[]" type="number" class="form-control total" placeholder="Total" required /></td>' + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Remove materials items"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>'
}

 var rowtoatal = 0;
//on change of qty
$(document).on('change keyup ', '.qty ', function() {

//get qty value
  var qty = $(this).val();
  //getting closest tr
  var elem = $(this).closest("tr");
  //get  price value
  var price = elem.find("td input.price").val();
  //check if price is not null
  if (price !== null && price !== '') {
    rowtoatal = qty * price;
    console.log(qty + " *  " + price + " = " + rowtoatal)
    //adding total to sub_total
    elem.find("td input.total").val(rowtoatal)

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="particulars_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Particular</td>
      <td>HSN</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">
        <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success w-100" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more Materials"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>Add</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: hello swati, here total is not getting auto calculated in same

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Current code will work only when quantity is clicked and if price value is not empty.